# Border color of Qt components

Tags: qt, colors, qframe

I want to change border color of QFrame component. Also tried with style sheet but no effect at run time. In my project there are various Dialog UI are there which are basically QFrame and i want to change the border color of selected dialog i.e. QFrame border color. Is there any workaround for that in QT.
As shown below there are two dialog when any one of selected it's respective frame border color should get changed

[image: Here is the snippet of which something i want to do]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
frame->setObjectName("myObject");
frame->setStyleSheet("#myObject { border: 5px solid black; }");
```

Comment: Thanks that had worked. Can you suggest me how can apply glowing effect on border. Is it possible in QT?

Comment: Yes, it is possible - I have not used this feature yet but take a look: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-glow.html