# Qt: How to delete the white lines?

Tags: qt

[image]

[image]

I want to delete the white lines of the tabwidget on the right and bottom side, but I don't know how.

I've tried to set the border-right-color and border-bottom-color, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What did you try? Code?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696850/border-color-of-qt-components

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it via `css`

Like that in `.qrc` in `.css`:

```
QTabWidget
{ 
   border: 3px solid grey; 
}
```

or via `QWidget::setStyleSheet(const QString &styleSheet)`